# Automate Flyway migration with Docker and Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, flyway

I'd like to automate the Flyway migrations for our MariaDB database. For testing purposes I added the following service to my `docker-compose.yml` running only the `info` command.

```
  flyway:
    image: boxfuse/flyway:5.2.4
    command: -url=jdbc:mariadb://mariadb_service -schemas=$${MYSQL_DATABASE} -table=schema_version -connectRetries=60 info
    volumes:
      - ./db/migration:/flyway/sql
    depends_on:
      - mariadb_service
```

This seems to be working, i.e. I can see the output of `info`.

Now I'd like to take this idea one step further and integrate this into our Jenkins build pipeline. This is where I get stuck.

1. If I deployed the Docker stack with the above `docker-compose.yml` in my `Jenkinsfile` would the corresponding stage fail upon errors during the migration? Speaking, would Jenkins notice that error?
2. If this is not true how can I integrate the Flyway migration in my Jenkins pipeline? I found that there is a Flyway Runner plugin but I didn't see if this can connect to a database in a Docker stack deployed by the `Jenkinsfile`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Jenkins built-in support for Docker](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/). Then your pipeline script may contain the stage

```java
stage('Apply DB changes') {

    agent {
        docker {
            image 'boxfuse/flyway:5.2.4'
            args '-v ./db/migration:/flyway/sql --entrypoint=\'\''
        }
    }

    steps {
        sh "/flyway/flyway -url=jdbc:mariadb://mariadb_service -schemas=${MYSQL_DATABASE} -table=schema_version -connectRetries=60 info"
    }

}
```

This way the `steps` will be executed within temporary Docker container created by Jenkins [`agent`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) from [`boxfuse/flyway`](https://hub.docker.com/r/boxfuse/flyway/) image. If the command fails the entire stage will fail as well.